# localStorage key not being created

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I am trying to store a key on both the current page, and an external page. In the example below I use google.
`url` and `x` are both defined in the function earlier on.

```
window.localStorage.setItem(url, x);
var url2 = "http://google.com/";
document.location = url2;
storeToDB(url, x);


function storeToDB(url, x) {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log("Waiting..."); }, 1000); 
    window.localStorage.setItem(url, x);
    document.location = url;
    console.log("Value Stored");
}
```

The method is called, however, the key is not stored.
The page looks as if it is being refreshed, so I know it is passing that line.

This code is running on a content-script on a chrome-extension.

Comment: You realize your _"Waiting..."_ message will appear after the operation has completed right? After the `setTimeout(...);` is set, the browser will continue to run through the rest of the JavaScript commands in your function.

Comment: @War10ck Can you please show me how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Setting location.href doesn't take effect until your script terminates.  As such, if you set it multiple times, only the last value you set it to will be navigated to.

More importantly, once the browser leaves a page, any scripts running on that page *will not keep running*.  It would be a massive security hole if you could navigate a browser to another page and execute arbitrary code there.

Comment: So how could I set localStorage on another page?

Comment: If you're talking about pages on the same domain - localStorage is already shared between those.  If you're talking about pages on a different domain - you can't touch their localStorage.

Comment: Keep in mind this is running from a content script in an extension, so I can add localStorage to any domain. It works one the first page, as I said, but not for the second.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation on content scripts, you cannot use localStorage from there. You can only use chrome.storage or use localStorage from a background page (by sending a message to it from the content script)

Comment: Well in the code before it it sets/uses localStorage values without problem.